# Static factories IntStream Exception while Foreach loop

Tags: collections, java-8, java-stream

Can Anyone help me why this case is giving the exception?

```
IntStream i = IntStream.of(6,5,7,1, 2, 3, 3);
    IntStream d = i.map(n -> n+1 );
    d.forEach(System.out::print);
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Origional Streams" );
    i.forEach(System.out::print);
```

Here is Output.

```
7682344
Origional Streams
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: stream has already been operated upon or closed
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.sourceStageSpliterator(AbstractPipeline.java:279)
at java.util.stream.IntPipeline$Head.forEach(IntPipeline.java:557)
```

Comment: this will be closed as a duplicate I bet... `d.forEach` and then `i.forEach` calling two terminal operations...

Comment: i also d.close(); also gives the same error. There is  Terminal operations on  both IntStreams i think they are thread safe.

Comment: yes there are two terminal operations.. you are calling `forEach` two times. what does thread safety has to do with this?

Comment: @Eugene can you please suggest me a solution for this. Don't you think there are two Streams. ? Each run independently ??

Comment: you create a supplier for this... `Supplier<IntStream> sup = () -> IntStream.of(6, 5, 7, 1, 2, 3, 3);` and call `sup.get()` to get a new `IntStream` all the time

Comment: Eugene is right, stream is designed for consuming once.

Comment: Eugene That is what i was looking for. Thanks, Mate!

Answer (score 0):

look that

```
d = i.map(n -> n + 1);
```

means that the stream d is taking the reference of the stream i, 
now forEach is a terminal operation, consuming the stream of i, affecting the ref on d too.

[image]